# Consuming a web service in multiple threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I am consuming a web service provided to me by a vendor in c# application. This application calls a web method in a loop and that slows down the performance. To get the complete set of results, it takes more than an hour.

Can I apply multi threading on my side to consume this web service in multiple threads and combine the results together?

Is there any better approach to retrieve data in minutes instead of hours?

Comment: It depends on your code. If you can provide codes, we can take a look at it and give you a better solution.

Comment: Probably not.  Unless the service is designed for multiple threads it will not work.  You can check the task manager to see if the service is using a lot of memory.  The service could be querying a large database which may account for slow performance.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would suggest that the service can't be called on concurrent threads. Is there any such thing as a web application that can't handle concurrent requests?

Comment: How many requests are you sending that it takes more than an hour? That will reveal something. If you're sending five requests and it takes an hour that's one thing. If it's 1,000 that's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to make sure your vendor **does indeed support this** or does not prohibit it (which is very probable too).

The code itself to do this is fairly straightforward, using a method such as `Parallel.For`

**Simple Example (google.com):**

```
Parallel.For(0, norequests,
               i => { 
                 //Code that does your request goes here
               } );
```

**Exaplanation:**

In a `Parallel.For` loop, all the requests get executed in-parallel (as implied in the name), which could potentially provide a very significant increase in performance.

**Further reading:**

[MSDN on Parallel.For loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask your vendor. We can only speculate about why it takes that long or if firing multiple requests will actually yield the same results as the one that takes long.

Basically, sending *one* request getting *one* response should beat the multi-threaded variant because it *should* be easier to optimize on the servers side.

If you want to know why this is not the case with the current version of the service, ask the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

This is only samples, if you call web services in parallel:

```
private void TestParallelForeach()
{
  string[] uris = {"http://192.168.1.2", "http://192.168.1.3", "http://192.168.1.4"};
  var results = new List<string>();
  var syncObj = new object();
  Parallel.ForEach(uris, uri =>
  {
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
      webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      try
      {
        var result = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
        lock (syncObj)
        {
          results.Add(result);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        // Do error handling here...
      }
    }
  });
  // Do with "results" here....
}
```